How Publish a React Native Web app on apache server and allow routing from url
I developed a react native application with expo 51 and I used react-native-web to publish a web version.
I do it by using this command :
npx expo export --platform web
and after I push all content in dist directory to my Apache server.
From a browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) I can view my web application if I type the root url (/) and I after I can navigate in other page in my application.
But if I type another url than root page (/home or /about) to launch my web application, than don't work !
In my application I use react router and normally some page must be directly opened from a specific url.
For example, I want to open home page when I type /home url and open about page when I type /about .
This work fine on my computer when I develop with expo (npx expo start --web) but this don't work on my production server.
How allow routing from url on my Apache server?
Is it possible ?
